# Archlinux, how to customize the login information?

Tags: command-line, arch-linux

Which file should I edit to customize the login information?

[image: login information]

How to custom the system startup information?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most distributions you can simply edit /etc/issue

If Arch is the case, I can say that it works.

look [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-change-login-message/) for a special character guide.

It's not a shell script though, it's only a description file, if you want to put other info into it, you should edit a service script or an init script to append the info you want to /etc/issue.

Comment: What if I want to display some dynamic information? Such as the machine's current IPv4 address?

Comment: That's not a simple matter.
/etc/issue is not a shell script, it's simply a parsed description file, some escape sequences are recognised, but you can't put shell commands there.
One way I can think to do it, is modifying your interface connection script, making it append your IP to /etc/issue.
I would advise against it, though, because you'll be slowing your login time by waiting the interface to come up.